# Displaying just the capital letters of a string

Tags: python

This sounds simple but how can i display the capital letters of a string like:

string = "Hey There"

Then displays

'HT'

Comment: Take a look at [str.isupper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
''.join([word[0] for word in s.split() if word[0].isupper()])
```

`s` being the string you want to find the capital letters, you split the string into words and choose those which have a upper case first letter.

In case you want all the capital letters off the string

```
''.join(c for c in s if c.isupper())
```

In this we check if every character `c` is upper case and join all such characters.

Comment: Explain your solution. Just giving one liner without explaining is no good except just giving the output. Without explanation, it's hard to make it transferable to other similar problems